# Weird Output of my R function

Tags: r

I have a small problem with my written R function. I programmed a little game where you have to guess a number. The game tells you if your guess is higher or lower than the number you have to guess. If you guess the right number the game ends.

Now the thing I dont unterstand:
When I start the game and enter the right number at the first iteration, everything is fine. 
But when I for example enter a character in the first iteration (which would be catched by the first if clause) and then enter the right number in the second interation (or any other iteration) I get my own error message, "unknown error occured", as well as warnings from R itself saying "In guess(x) : NAs introduced by coercion".

Obviously my programm is not able to define whether the number given by the user is equal to the generated number. At least not in every iteration except the first one. But Why?

The if clauses about the input being higher or lower than the generated number work as expected.

I hope someone can help me/explain me what i did wrong :) Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
guess <- function(rng) {
  cat("Which number are we looking for?", "\n")
  a <- readline()
  # print(a)
  if (is.na(as.numeric(a))) {
    cat("Please enter a number!", "\n")
    guess(rng)
  }
  a <- as.numeric(a)
  # cat("rng is", rng)
  if (a == rng) {
    return("Congratulations! You guessed right - 100 points for you!")
  }
  if (a < rng) {
    cat("The number we are looking for is greater than your guessed number!", "\n")
    guess(rng)
  }

  if (a > rng) {
    cat("The number we are looking for is lower than you guessed number!", "\n")
    guess(rng)
  }
  stop("Unknown error occured!")
}


guessTheNumber <- function(lower_border=1, upper_border=5) {
  x <- as.numeric(sample(lower_border:upper_border, 1))
  cat("The number we are looking for is", x, ".", "\n") # for testing purposes
  guess(x)
}
```

Comment: Just delete the `stop()` line and change `return()` to `cat()` for the correct answer.

Comment: Hi LAP, thanks for the quick response. This helped in some ways. If I only enter numbers the game works. But as soon as I enter a character and then the right number in the next interation, i get the following: 

Congratulations! You guessed right - 100 points for you! Error in if (a ==rng) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In guess(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In guess(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

Do you know why this happens?
And what was wrong with my return() statement?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has a similar problem:

The problem are the **environments of functions in R**. Every time a function is called it creates its own environment (with variables, values, ...). So when a function calls itself, and the called itself ends, the calling function is still alive as well as its environment. So this function continues, which makes my first if-clause senseless. That causes the problem with the character input.

So problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would have used if -- else if -- else, then it would have worked just fine

```
guess <- function(rng) {
  cat("Which number are we looking for?", "\n")
  a <- readline()
  # print(a)
  if (is.na(as.numeric(a))) {
    cat("Please enter a number!", "\n")
    guess(rng)
  } else{
    a <- as.numeric(a)
    # cat("rng is", rng)
    if (a == rng) {
      return("Congratulations! You guessed right - 100 points for you!")
    } else if (a < rng) {
      cat("The number we are looking for is greater than your guessed number!", "\n")
      guess(rng)
    } else if (a > rng) {
      cat("The number we are looking for is lower than you guessed number!", "\n")
      guess(rng)
    } else stop("Unknown error occured!")
  }
}
```

Comment: But it doenst solve the environment issue. The calling function still tries to compare a character with a number. I didnt have time to resolve this yet. I probably have to remove the environments manually. But thanks for the help :)